# How to delete ANY row containing specific string in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, filter, multiple-columns

I know that there are many ways to delete rows containing a specific value in a column in python, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this by checking all columns in a dataset at once and deleting all rows that contain a specific value WITHOUT turning it into NaN and dropping all of them. To clarify, I don't want to lose all columns with strings/NaN I just want to lose rows that have a specific value.

For example, I'm looking to delete all rows with participants that contain an answer "refused" in any column. So if my table looked like this:

| Subject | Race | Gender | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | black | female | 123 |
| 2 | white | refused | 145 |
| 3 | white | male | 165 |
| 4 | asian | male | refused |
| 5 | refused | male | 128 |
| 6 | white | male | nan |
| 7 | asian | male | refused |
| 8 | black | male | nan |

I would want to implement a statement that would filter it to keep only subjects that didn't have any responses with a string containing "refused":

| Subject | Race | Gender | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | black | female | 123 |
| 3 | white | male | 165 |
| 6 | white | male | nan |
| 8 | black | male | nan |

Does anyone know how to filter this way across an entire dataset?

Comment: [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) is for handling missing values.

Comment: Do you want to match exxactly 'refused' or if the answer contains 'refused'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `isin` with `any`.

```py
df = df[~df.isin(['refused']).any(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
df = df[(df.Gender != 'refused') & (df.Race != 'refused').... ]
```

or alternatively

```
filter = reduce(lambda column1, column2: (df[column1] != 'refused') & (df[column2] != 'refused'), df.columns)
df = df[filter]
```

Comment: I think the idea is that 'refused' can appear in any column. It's a missing value, basically.

Comment: @kwinkunks See update

Answer (score -2):

Another method with apply-lambda:

```
df = df.loc[~df.apply(lambda row : any('refused' in str(cell) for cell in row) ,axis=1)]
```